# How do you restrict access rights to your clickonce web repository?

Tags: security, deployment, .htaccess, clickonce

I've built and successfully deployed a ClickOnce application.

The application successfully updates when needed, and everything works fine.

However, I don't like the fact than everybody on the internet can access the files freely (even if he's not one of my customers)

Since I have only a small number of clients (huge corporations), I've restricted the access to my client IPs using a .htaccess file as follows :

```
AddType application/x-ms-application application
AddType application/x-ms-manifest manifest
AddType application/octet-stream deploy

<LIMIT GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.2.3.4
allow from 5.6.7.8
....
....
</LIMIT>
```

Unfortunately, this solution is not automated, and doesn't work well with mobile users.

How do you deal with this situation?

Comment: if you aren't authenticating users, your options are pretty limited.  is the ip address the only thing you can go off of to identify a user?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the user aren't connecting ; clickonce is, and seems to only support windows authentication (with IIS), which is of course not an option on the Internet ...

Comment: Is the question still relevant?